# Merging NPM dependancy with a VUE.js Javascript Project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, node-modules

For a particular case in a Vue.js and JavaScript project a NPM package dependency have to be merge with the current JavaScript code base.

In that specific case, the NPM package should not be part of the nodes_modules folder anymore but rather be part of the JavaScript code itself.

In that case as both codebases will grow together in the future. (Independently from the original NPM package and not as a Fork)

How can I merge or fusion a NPM package to a Javascript project?

Additional Details:

- The library that need to be merge is [OIDC client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js). It's an open source project "Archived" by it's author (So no possibility to create Pull Request for a new release).
- It is use to create a SSO for an internal project. This library has been retain by architect the for specific need of the project and there is no other option than this one.
- There is no "internal package manager" available in this company
- I don't want to host the fork on my personal Github and manage the package on NPM website

Comment: Can you explain your case? What kind of merge do you expect? What kind of project is it, a library?

Comment: The expecting result is a JavaScript project.

Comment: Again, can you explain your case? It's unclear what is your situation. The question doesn't make sense in general because you could just copy the source code of some packages to your app, but this won't work with other ones

Comment: sure see above "Additional Details" section, thank you!

Comment: This could be XY problem. Doesn't the company have private repo? A fork (not necessarily github) could be maintained separately from the project and installed through npm directly from a repo without publishing it in npm repo, this is the straightforward way. Otherwise it could be placed into project dir and installed as local npm dep

Comment: No private repo indeed. The project dir could be a good way to go, but it would need to be commit in the AzureDevOp repo to be deploy with the project. Any clue how to do this Estus?

Comment: I don't deal with Azure, can't say. Any way, my suggestion is to keep a fork in private git repo and npm install it from there directly.

Comment: AzureDevOp is a repo like Github with other integrated feature like pipeline. The deployment process in the pipeline force restore all npm package (So no node_modules is ever store in the project repo).  That why I would need to have this dependency hard coded somehow in the project. That is really best direction to go, I just have no idea "how to do this in a clean way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempt to solve this problem, it turn out that [Patch-Package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) do the best job to merge a dependency by simply patching over instead of forking.

Syntax is pretty simple and it integrate very well with NPM:

1. Installation: `npm i patch-package`
2. Modify the code of your dependency directly in `node_modules` folder
3. Run `npx patch-package some-package` where some-package is the name of your package to patch

https://github.com/ds300/patch-package

Documentation: https://github.com/ds300/patch-package